# Facing Performance Issue post replacing the OCI driver with THIN driver

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

HiAll,

I have a spring based web application developed using Java/J2EE,spring core,spring mvc,spring-jdbc&spring security.The application has used OCI driver with OracleOCIConnectionPool datasource. I have changed the driver from OCI to THIN and replaced the OracleOCIConnectionPool with OracleConnectionPoolDataSource. After replacing the oci driver with thin driver we are facing too much performance issue.
Please suggest your answers to improve the performance.

Regards
Subbareddy

Comment: Interesting question, but it would help if you outlined the issues you are facing. What is taking more time with the thin driver? What is your application doing?

Comment: There are some functionalities,when I click on the any functional link its  taking long time for displaying the data as compared with the  oci driver.
For OCI driver :Its taking 1 or 2 seconds to display the data in front end where as its taking 15 to 20  sec to display the data with thin driver.

Regards
Subbareddy